# Add X, Y column to a ESRI shapefile using ogr2ogr

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr

I've a point ESRI shapefile in ESPG32632 spatial reference.

I need to add X and Y column to it and I'd like to use something from command line like ogr2ogr but I don't know the syntax.

Any example?

Comment: What have you tried?  Placing your best effort in the question allows other to identify your mistake, not create a potentially inappropriate example.  Please [edit] the question to specify the topology type of the source shapefile.

Comment: Sorry @Vince for the generic question ... I've a point shapefile in EPSG32632 ... I know how to do it for example in spatialite but I've to do it using something from command line so I've thought to ogr2ogr ...

Comment: Please **edit the question** in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer your question to have to min the comments for critical information. Even though you've been here a while, you still haven't take the [Tour], which explains your responsibilities as someone asking a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the OGR SQL http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html and add X and Y columns with

```
ogrinfo foo.shp -sql "alter table foo add column X double" 
ogrinfo foo.shp -sql "alter table foo add column Y double"
```

Then switch to SQLite dialect http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql_sqlite.html

```
ogrinfo foo.shp -dialect SQLite -sql "update foo set X=ST_X(geometry)"
ogrinfo foo.shp -dialect SQLite -sql "update foo set Y=ST_Y(geometry)"
```