# Adding Lon, Lat column to shapefile in EPSG 32632 using ogr2ogr

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr

I've a point shapefile in ESPG 32632 spatial reference.

To add X and Y columns I've used [Add X, Y column to a ESRI shapefile using ogr2ogr](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/236662/add-x-y-column-to-a-esri-shapefile-using-ogr2ogr) and it works fine.

Now I need to add also Lat and Lon columns to store coordinates in EPSG4326 and I'd like to use something from command line like ogr2ogr but I don't know the syntax.

Any example?

Comment: A good question should include your attempt and detail of what happens when you try it.  What have you tried?  Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is the same of [Add X, Y column to a ESRI shapefile using ogr2ogr](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/236662/add-x-y-column-to-a-esri-shapefile-using-ogr2ogr) you cited, except that we have to transform the geometry to EPSG:4326 in order to calculate the geographical coordinates using for instance the SpatiaLite [`ST_Transform`](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.3.0.html#p15) function:

```
ogrinfo points.shp -sql "ALTER TABLE points ADD COLUMN LON double" 
ogrinfo points.shp -sql "ALTER TABLE points ADD COLUMN LAT double"
ogrinfo points.shp -dialect SQLite -sql "UPDATE points SET LON=ST_X(ST_Transform(geometry,4326))"
ogrinfo points.shp -dialect SQLite -sql "UPDATE points SET LAT=ST_Y(ST_Transform(geometry,4326))"
```